# How much can you bring from Skyrim SE to Skyrim VR?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr

I read an [article](https://uploadvr.com/use-mods-skyrim-vr-pc/) the other day that suggested Skyrim VR is now moddable by PC users via mod managers.  The current limitations are as one would expect:

- No SKSE yet; the devs have made it clear that this requires a lot of work involving the new addresses under the hood, so SKSE-required mods are not currently supported
- No physics model/skeleton changes work yet.   This means UNP bodies with the physics model and CBP use in general doesn't work yet
- Fores New Idles (FNIS) doesn't work yet

Right now, this kills most of my mods that affect gameplay (my needs mods, some of my companions, and things requiring FNIS) but should keep tree replacers and body replacers intact.  The Unofficial Patch also works, and all DLC are included with SVR.

My question is, what about saves and such?  I've been doing another playthrough in SE and have cleared the College of Winterhold and Thieves Guild quests. I can see the benefit of just starting from scratch, but when you're 80 hours in, that's harder to stomach than if you're 800 hours in, since you just did everything.   What specifically will and will not port over, beyond just certain mods?

Comment: I'm not even sure vanilla saves would make it over.  Modded saves are probably a non-starter.

Comment: That depends really on whether or not it is save breaking to load the save without the mod installed.  The real question is, are the saves at all portable, but I don't know if anyone has tried yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the exception of SKSE, both CBBE and many, many mods work well with VR.  In fact, I have both FNIS and XP32 running, along with 35 other mods.

Limitations: anything that needs SKSE or SKSE-reliant mods.  First person mods are a bit hit-and-miss, since your person is at a non-visible angle.  Skyrim VR with the 2017 textures, RLO, and VWDE is ludicrously pretty.